# Adobe AIR Mobile App - exclude ANEs when running on desktop

Tags: compiler-construction, air, adobe, fdt

I'm using [FDT Free](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/buy-download/) for developing a little game on mobile apps. For controlling the game, the Gyroscope is required, therefore I've added Adobe's [gyroscope AIR extension](http://extensionsforair.com/extensions/gyroscope/) (ANE and SWC) to the lib folder of my project.

When testing on a mobile device, the extension works fine; however, when trying to run the app as a desktop application, I receive the following error:

> The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension: Error: Requested extension com.adobe.gyroscope is not supported for Windows-x86.

For excluding code that uses the gyroscope on the desktop run configuration, I've added the following arguments to the compiler arguments:

```
-define+=CONFIG::MOBILEDEVICE,false
-define+=CONFIG::DESKTOP,true
```

Also, I've added code snippets for not compiling certain parts of my code that use the extension:, e.g.:

```
CONFIG::MOBILEDEVICE {
if (Gyroscope.isSupported) 
{
    gyro = new Gyroscope(); 
    gyro.setRequestedUpdateInterval(1000); 
    gyro.addEventListener(GyroscopeEvent.UPDATE, onGyroUpdate); 
}
```

Using conditional compiling works fine, but what can I do to prevent the ANE and SWC from being included when running my desktop run configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell if the source code for this extension is available, but if it is, it might be easier for you to simply build support for a default platform into the extension than to worry about conditional compilation. You can visit http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt2.html and read the section on creating a default library to understand how it is to be done. It just requires a simple AS3 project with stub methods that match the public interface of the NE. Then you can compile the NE and it will work without problems on any platform.